# Sum values but avoid repetitions - Excel formula

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I need help summing values in a column avoiding to sum twice the ones with same ID.

```
   ID   |  Value
-----------------
  7001  |   500
  7002  |   200
  7003  |   300
  7001  |   500
  7004  |   300
  7005  |   600
  7003  |   400
  7006  |   100
```

Expected result: 2000

Can somebody help me with the formula?

Thanks in advance!
MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a helper column, in **C2** enter:

=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,0,1)

and copy down, then in another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B9*C2:C9)
```

[image]